# A for loop works in Python but doest work in Django

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I need to parse h2 tags from the site. 
I use BeautifulSoup

Here is the Views.py part. I search for all the H2 tags

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        url = request.POST.get('web_link', None)
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}#headers
        source=requests.get(url, headers=headers).text # url source
        #bs
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')


        # Title INFO
        title_num = soup.find_all('title')
        title_num = len(title_num)
        title = soup.title.text
        title_len = len(title)


        # H1 INFO
        h1_num = soup.find_all('h1')
        h1_num = len(h1_num)
        h1 = soup.h1.text

        # H2 INFO
        h2_all = soup.find_all('h2')
        h2_num = len(h2_all)

        return render(request, 'tags/django-bs.html', {
            'title':title,
            'title_len':title_len,
            'title_num':title_num,
            'h1_num':h1_num,
            'h1':h1,
            'h2_all':h2_all,
            'h2_num':h2_num,
            'h21':h21
            })

    return render(request, 'tags/django-bs.html')
```

Here is the Template part:

```
<h2>H2 info</h2>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Test</th>
            <th scope="col">Value</th>
            <th scope="col">Result</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>H2 quantity:</td>
            <td>{{ h2_num }}</td>
            <td>None</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>H2</td>
            <td>{{ h2_all }}</td>
            <td>None</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>H2 tags:</td>
            <td>
              {% for h2 in h2_all %}
                {{ h2 }}
              {% endfor %}
            </td>
            <td>E</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

In the template part.
When I try to display h2_all - it works. The result is:
`[<h2>Запись к врачу</h2>, <h2>Запись на диагностику</h2>]`

But when I'm trying to loop to get each of h2 tag.

```
{% for h2 in h2_all %}
  {{ h2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

The result is the following: `[] []`

I'a a beginner and this is my first project on Django. I've already spent several hours trying to solve the problem, but have no result...
Please help...

Comment: I've added more code from view

Comment: I've added template part to the question

Comment: Yes, ```{{ h2_all }}``` is OK. It displays it on the site. 

i've already tried to add print and return. If I do so, it gives me an error - http://prntscr.com/rrk8vq

Comment: try to remove return in html template

Comment: @djangodjames how many items you get from h2 all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to convert BeautifulSoup tags to strings before passing them to a view?

You can use something like this:

```py
# H2 INFO
h2_all = soup.find_all('h2')
h2_all = [h.text for h in h2_all]
```

This is required because `find_all()` method returns `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` objects, that can't be represented in Django templates.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
{% for h2t in h2_all.get_text %}
  <h2>{{ h2t }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

if you have h2_all only 1 item so for loop will not work

how many items you get in h2_all?

Comment: I have 2 items in H2

Comment: If I try the same code in Python, not in Django. It works well. It gives two h2 tags as a result

Comment: ```
{% for h2t in h2_all %}
  <h2>{{ h2t.get_text }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```
I've tryed. The result is the following: http://prntscr.com/rrkhoc it shows the list

Comment: @djangodjames try now!